# In CMake, how to pack shared_library in Cpack debian package?

Tags: cmake

I am new to CMake. I have a project of structure :
MainBranch
|_____ lib1
|_____ lib2
|_____ lib3
|_____ lib4

Now I want to treat my lib3 as shared library. I have created FindLib3.cmake file using which I am able to use find_package() to successfully find the library. Now my question is, I want to create CmakeLists.txt for lib3 such that when I do find_package(), if the LIB3_FOUND variable is set, it will find and link the library but if it not found, do as normal that it build the library using make and install it using install.

Now I am also packaging all the libraries into debian package so I am not sure how this will work.If I build the library normally I am using cpack_add_component() to add binary files. But if the library's .so file is found, how do I add this .so file in the debian package?

Comment: ` if the LIB3_FOUND variable is set, it will find and link the library but if it not found, do as normal that it build the library using make and install it using install.` - Just implement that conditional work using `if`. What is a problem with that direct approach?

Comment: I had another which I wrote in description because of character limit for title. I have edited the title with that question as well.

Comment: Your edited question is very different than your original one. Why don't you submit a new question?